# Show that $(a, x) \sim (b, y) \iff w(ay - bx) = 0, \text{ for some } w \in S$ defines an equivalence relation on $R \times S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, equivalence-relations, localization

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring (that does not necessarily include $1$),
> and let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $R$.
>
> Show that the relation defined on the set $R \times S$ by $$(a, x)
>  \sim (b, y) \iff w(ay - bx) = 0, \text{ for some } w \in S $$ is an
> equivalence relation on $R \times S$.

Obviously if $R$ is a field (or even an integral domain), this is somewhat trivial; but the possibility of zero divisors is making this kind of frustrating.

Reflexivity and symmetry are easy enough. Transitivity is giving me some trouble, though...

I'll lay it out: Suppose that $(a,x) \sim (b,y)$ and $(b,y) \sim (c, z)$. Then there exist $u,v \in S$ such that $u(ay - bx) = 0 = v(bz - cy)$. We seek a $w \in S$ such that $w(az - cx) = 0$.

Now, if $R$ is a *field*, we can simply choose $w = y$ since (after solving for $az$ and $cx$), we have
$$ az - cx = bxzy^{-1} - bzxy^{-1} \implies y(az - cx) = bxz - bxz = 0. $$
I tried to reverse engineer this observation to treat the more general case, but I just ended up pushing around symbols for an eternity...

Comment: Would your symbol pushing be easier if you restated it as "$uay = ubx$", etc.?

Answer (score 1):

(With some help from @JonathanZ supports MonicaC)

Take $w = uvy \in S$. Then
\begin{align*}
 uvy(az - cx) &= uvyaz - uvycx \\
              &= (uay)vz - uvcyx \\
              &= ubxvz - uvcyx.
\end{align*}
Since
$$ v(bz - cy) =  0 \implies uvx(bz - cy) = 0 \implies uvbxz - uvxcy = 0, $$
the proof is complete.

Comment: It's amazing what a difference it makes, isn't it?